# File transfering from Windows 2008 R2 to Windows 7 client is tremendously slow

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-7, file-transfer

I have main office and one branch. We have PTP 700mbit/s connection across them, and 1gb/s LAN at each office. 
The file server is at main office and its run on Windows 2008R2 Enterprise. Lately one of clients from branch office met the huge issue, that his download speed rate from the file server is sometimes at 50kb/s and about 300kb/s average. I also have to mention that it works that way for any of file resources at main office.(file transfer across local network is just fine)

I tried to workaround with netsh tunning stuff which is most common recommendation for related issues.(sadly its no use, i can get speed up to 600kb/s but then it goes down once again)

```
netsh int ip set global taskoffload=disabled
netsh int tcp set global congestion=none
netsh int tcp set global autotuning=disabled
netsh int tcp set global rss=disabled
```

I mostly used file manager (such as FAR file manager) and it occasionally notified me that the network path is not avaliable. (Never happened using explorer copy/paste, though the speed is just the same)

I also noticed that is when I upload something to the file server from that machine speed is just fine, at around 30mb/s.

Me and my colleagues are at branch office as well and we don't have issues like that. We also run Windows 7.(we have good speed on download/upload for both main/branch office)

I tried to change the ethernet path cord, reinstalled NIC drivers on client machine - no use.

The worst thing is hes probably the only one user at the office who has this type of issue.

Client machine is on the same as file sources VLAN.

The latency is mostly 1ms.

Client machine was working fine for some time now(mabye 6 months)(i.e its not freshly cloned).

The network admin claims nothing on cisco switches is blocking or limit his connection speed.

What could cause a problem and how to diagnose it correctly?

Appreciated on any advices.

Comment: a bit more detail on exactly what you tried tuning would be useful. What's the latency over the link? Does this member of staff have a non-standard software image or is everyone running identical cloned machines?

What happens if you run some tests using iperf?

Comment: Also: Is it worth burning hours on troubleshooting this issue vs giving him a different, freshly installed machine?

Comment: @AgentK Is this guy on the same vlan as everyone else?

Comment: Best to update your original question with the extra details rather than burying them in this thread, too :)

Comment: @AgentK: What is the version of tcpip.sys on the client and server?

Comment: Capture traffic on the client when it's having problems. You'll find you answer there 9 out of 10 times.

Comment: File server's tcpip.sys file version 6.1.7601.18148

Comment: Client's machine tcpip.sys file version 6.1.7601.18438

Comment: Try a different machine (laptop for example) on the same cable he is using. And make sure to test multiple hosts across your 700 Mbps link. You have to find the point where there is a problem... only knowing it's between that machine and the other building doesn't help.

Comment: Have you installed http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2775511 and the additional vortices mentioned in the KB article on both the servers and workstations?

Answer (score 0):

Another command that may have implications (REF: http://www.speedguide.net/articles/windows-7-vista-2008-tweaks-2574):

netsh int tcp set heuristics disabled

Otherwise, I'd probably go to network monitor/wireshark at this point.  You need to compare the exact same file(s) uploading/downloading to/from the same server but with different clients - the one that is having trouble, another one in the same office that is not having trouble, and if that doesn't show anything useful to look at closer, one of your own machines from a different office.  Generally seeing these sets in comparison will give you some insight - are you seeing repeated retransmissions?  Is the window size extra big (timeouts) or extra small (lots of overhead setting up/tearing down sessions)?